# assertTrue statement requires static import in intelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I just shifted my project form Netbeans to intelliJ IDEA, its a junit based test project. In netbeans I was using statments

```
assertTrue("Message", conditionCustom());
```

and it was working without any extra import. Now when using the same above command in intelliJ I have to import file

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
```

is there any way so I dont need to write the above line in my code file? otherwise I have to edit all my files to get working assertTrue statement.

Comment: Are you sure you weren't using JUnit 3 before, and JUnit 4 now?

Comment: I am not sure. but in intelliJ why I need to add junit to my classpath to get it working? I am using maven based project now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You either have to add the static import OR make clear what class that static call is associated with:

```
Assert.assertTrue("Message", conditionCustom());
```

I usually use the latter because I think it's clearer.

Java won't compile unless it can figure out which class to associate that static method with.

I'd guess that perhaps you use inheritance to associate that static method with your test.

Comment: The example would be better off using `Assert.fail("Message")`. Believe it or not, I've inherited code where the previous developer repeatedly used `Assert.true(false);` to indicate failure (hope they didn't learn it from here).

Comment: My example should not have done what you're implying.  I've edited to make it look like the original question.